Planar graph problem
In a parliament of $n$ people there are several (pairwise distinct in composition) commissions with 3 people in each. It is known that if two people are in some commission, then they are in exactly two commissions. Such two commissions are called adjacent. It is also known that any two people are in some two corresponding commissions that can be connected by a sequence of commissions in which any two neighboring commissions are adjacent. Prove that the number of commissions is not less than $2 n-4$.
I know a solution to this problem using combinatorial topology, which considers a 2-complex in a five-dimensional space. However, I do not understand it, so I tried to limit myself to graph theory. How correct is my solution?
Graph Model:
Vertices: Represent the $ n $ members.
Edges: Connect members who share a committee.
Faces: Represent committees.
This graph is connected.
Since in our graph each face is a triangle, and each edge belongs to exactly two faces, the graph can be considered as a skeleton of a convex polyhedron whose surface is divided into triangles.
The frame (skeleton) of any convex polyhedron is a planar graph; therefore, our graph is planar.
By Euler's formula for planar graphs:
$$
V - E + F = 2,
$$
where $ V = n $, $ E $ is the number of edges, and $ F $ is the number of faces (committees).
Each face is a triangle ($ 3F $ incidences), and each edge belongs to two faces ($ 2E $ incidences). Thus:
$$
2E = 3F \quad \implies \quad E = \frac{3F}{2}.
$$
Substitute into Euler's formula:
$$
n - \frac{3F}{2} + F = 2.
$$
Simplify:
$$
n - \frac{F}{2} = 2 \quad \implies \quad F = 2n - 4.
$$
Thus:
The number of committees $ F $ satisfies:
$$
F \geq 2n - 4.
$$

I see nothing that prevents the structure from being, for example, toroidal instead of planar - such as this picture.

In fact, it's possible to construct dramatically nonplanar examples (though they will contain even more committees). For example, take the finite projective plane over $\mathbb F_3$ (with $13$ points and $13$ four-point lines) and replace each line by four committees, one for every three-point subset of the line. This satisfies the conditions in the problem, and for $13$ people, there are $52$ committees. (Notably, in this setup, every pair of people is on two committees together, so the associated graph is the complete graph $K_{13}$, and we get $V-E+F = -13$.)

Any ideas on how to fix the solution in this case?

I have been trying to think of a way to induct by removing vertices of degree $\le 5$ (since if these do not exist, then we are done), and adding some new committees to replace the ones that are missing. But it's hard to make sure the committees that need to be added don't already exist.
